# Как вернуть custom json response в .net core web api?

Tags: c#, json, веб-программирование, asp.net, api

Вот метод, который должен возвращать json вида
`{ "status":"ready","timestamp":"2017-12-17"}`

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(Guid id)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       return BadRequest();

    Task task = db.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    if (task == null)
        return NotFound();

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(task);

    return Ok(json);
}
```

Объект `task` содержит три поля, поэтому я не могу вернуть просто `task`.
Он содержит поля: `Id, Time, Status`. Мне нужно вернуть в формате `json` только `Time` и `Status`. Как вручную прописать `json` так и не нашел.

Comment: Обычно делают т.н. ViewModel классы для отдачи наружу или приема в экшен метод. Сделайте класс и его сериализуйте. И маленькая ремарка: называть собственные классы также как дотнетовские, я имею в виду ваш класс `Task` - жуткое зло, так делать не надо.

Comment: Если данных очень мало, то можно попробовать через анонимные типы еще, к примеру так `var data = new {Status = "readu", Timestamp = DateTime.Now};`. Но соглашусь, лучше создать отдельно класс и с ним работать.

Comment: @Bulson да, соглашусь, постараюсь так не делать больше. Просто разве ручного способа нет? Только через класс?

Comment: Я лично не знаю как в Asp.net, но в asp.net core есть такая вещь, как `return Json(task);`, что сразу должен вернуть объект в json формате. Также, в нем вроде использовался JSON.NET, что позволяет использовать весь его функционал (к примеру, запретить сериализовать id, путем добавления атрибута `[JsonIgnore]`. Так что посмотрите, может есть аналог.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как как тогда указать StatusCode вместе с отсылаемым Json?

Comment: @kot_mapku3 Ну вот как [пример](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-api-with-asp-net-core-day-three-working-with-http-status-codes-in-asp/), но это Core, я не знаю есть ли это все в обычном asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View:

```
<h2>Home</h2>
<p id="contentId"></p>
<p id="contentValue"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "/Home/GetJson/?Id=" + 0);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState != 4
            || request.responseText == null) {
            return;
        }

        var obj = JSON.parse(request.response);
        console.log(obj);
        document.getElementById("contentId").innerHTML = obj.variable1;
        document.getElementById("contentValue").innerHTML = obj.variable2;
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public object GetJson(string Id)
{
    return new { Variable1 = Id, Variable2 = "Value"  };
}
```

Comment: Но оно так не работает. И ведь эти переменные не объявлены

Comment: Что именно не работает? [Пример](https://ibb.co/nHTF1T). В консоли видно, что json объект получен и его переменные использованы

Comment: Возвращет json по прямому запросу [Ткнуть сюда](https://ibb.co/iXbw88)

Comment: https://preview.ibb.co/ebqpT8/2018_05_24_13_01_44.png
Вот оно красным подчеркивает и говорит, что нельзя вот это преобразовать в IActionResult

Comment: Ну можно так, какая разница `public IActionResult GetJson(string Id)
{
    return Ok(new { Variable1 = Id, Variable2 = "Value" });
}`

Comment: Дело в том, что IActionResult указывает, что на выходе ожидается объект, реализующий IActionResult, Который анонимный метод не реализует. Поэтому можно вернуть Ok, инициализированный анонимным методом.